# How do I use a timer to run code again and again until a boolean value e.g. Testing is equal to true?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

This is probably a very easy question but, How do I use a timer to run code again and again until a boolean value e.g. Testing is equal to true?

Obviously I would use a while loop but I don't want it to stop the rest of the work taking place on the main ui thread

Comment: Well, I don't know if it works with android or if it is a good idea but there's this Quartz library... It's kinda heavy though...

Comment: what are do while loop for??

Comment: Use can try using IntentService With Runnable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process is running simultaneously, use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and use its [postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) to post a callback implementing the [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface.

A rather naive example:

```
final handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    if (<EXPRESSION>) {
        // Evaluated true, do your stuff and exit the polling loop.
    } else {
        handler.postDelayed(this, <TIMEOUT>);
    }
}

handler.postDelayed(r, <TIMEOUT>);
```

Comment: To confirm if I throw the boolean variable 'testing' into where expression is, upon testing being true the handler will stop.

Comment: Yep, it will no longer post itself to be run later

Comment: Beware that the function run() will still execute on the main ui thread. There are ways of launching the handler in its own thread but its a liability as any changes to views must be done on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager class to manage your thread. its simple to use.

for more info you can visit [Android SDK Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
         timer=new Timer();
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            // Do your task
            if(flagIsOn)
            {
             timer.cancel();
             timer.purge();
             }


            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```